# How do we install Linux as third OS side by side installation

Tags: system-installation

How do we install Linux as third side-by-side OS installation after Windows and Linux dual boot installation?

Comment: In a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

Install your third OS on an empty partition or add it to a new disk.

From the disk with the grub installation, ensure `os-prober` is installed and rerun `grub-mkconfig` to find the new OS and add it to the grub menu.